# make errors undefined reference to

Tags: c, linker-errors

I'm using a headless image and compiling this simple code in GNU bash. I receive these linker errors

```
#include <IL/il.h>   
#include <IL/ilu.h> 
#include <IL/ilut.h>   
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>   

int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{     
    ILuint  ImgId;

 // Initialize DevIL.   
    ilInit();   

    // Generate the main image name to use.   
    ilGenImages(1, &ImgId);   

    // Bind this image name.   
    ilBindImage(ImgId);   

    // Loads the image specified by File into the image named by ImgId.   
    if (!ilLoadImage(argv[1])) {   
        printf("Could not open file...exiting.\n");   
        return 3;   
    }   

    // Display the image's dimensions to the end user.   
    printf("Width: %d  Height: %d  Depth: %d  Bpp: %d\n",   
           ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),   
           ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT),   
           ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_DEPTH),   
           ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL));   

    return 0;
}
```

```
root@parallella:/home/parallella/parallella-examples/lena# make display
cc     display.c   -o display
/tmp/ccSqb23j.o: In function `main':
display.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `ilInit'
display.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `ilGenImages'
display.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `ilBindImage'
display.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `ilLoadImage'
display.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `ilGetInteger'
display.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `ilGetInteger'
display.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `ilGetInteger'
display.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `ilGetInteger'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [display] Error 1
```

How can I fix this linker problem?

Comment: You need to link with the DevIL library: `cc display.c -o display -L</path/to/DevIL/lib/dir> -l<DevIL lib name>`.

Comment: thank you but I'm using headless linux image, I don't have a desktop to go look for the path to DevIL library , what GNU bash instruction which make me find the library directory

Comment: Try `cc display.c -o display -lIL`.

Comment: the output for `cc display.c -o display -lIL` was nothing when I try to run using `./display` I receive  `could not open file ...existing.`

Comment: Because you did not pass a filename to the program, so `if (!ilLoadImage(argv[1]))` will be true.

Comment: ah ok sorry , thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are `ilInit`, `ilGenImages`, etc. defined? That is - which source file/pre-compiled library holds them?
You need to provide that information to cc.

Assuming these are defined in a source file called `foo.c`, the solution will be:

`cc display.c foo.c -o display`

In further details, this error rises when the compiler has the correct declarations for your functions (in your header files), but no definition (actual binary or sources to create that binary) are found.

Comment: how can I know where are ilInit, ilGenImages, etc. are defined?

Comment: I'm using a headless image running in parallella board only connected to UART terminal, how can I look for the source files, where exactly?

Comment: Normally, compilation and linking steps are separate in makefiles to allow for incremental builds. Your solution uses compilation and linking in one step, which is rather rare.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin But still it should work... As for where those source files/libraries are located, this is something only you can tell. I am not familiar with these functions, perhaps you can point me to where you got the reference from?

Comment: It should work. However, you would not put that in a makefile because that would make incremental builds build more than necessary.